# Undesired information in sent email headers

Tags: email, email-server, mailing-list

I have a script that uses the PHP mail() method to send mail to a number of users that have signed up to receive a mailing list from my site.

Since migrating to the new Endurance platform, I noticed the following additional headers being inserted in the headers of messages I've sent:

```
X-EN-Info: U=pow.(my user name here) P=(path to scriptname here)
X-EN-CGIUser: pow.(my user name here)
X-EN-CGIPath: (path to scriptname here)
X-EN-OrigIP: (my local IP here)
```

This reveals quite a bit of information to the email recipient that they do NOT need to know. Primarily I'm concerned with it showing the location of my mailing script (even though it's .htaccess protected, that info does NOT need publicizing), but I'm also sensitive about my Powweb username and home IP address being revealed.

Does anybody know why these headers are added? Can they be configured to NOT be sent? I can't imagine what possible good could come from having this information revealed.

Thanks,

Comment: Okay-- this is really oddball. This question is an *exact* copy/paste from a question on another site dated 2006. What gives?  http://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-66389.html  Is this some attempt to game Server Fault or something?

Comment: i have the same issue and i need to solve it, therefor i cope and past question here

Comment: @AshrafHamdy This is really between you and your provider. Those are custom headers being added by their system, and telling you how to circumvent that is not our place. (If *you* are the provider you need to understand your environment better - We can't know for sure where these are being injected into the mail - I couldn't even guess reliably with the information provided.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely normal for your local IP address to show in the email headers.  It's been that way pretty much since email was invented.

The other headers are there so that when your email is reported as spam, they can be tracked to the user who actually sent the message, so they can be dealt with appropriately.

Most (legitimate) bulk mailing systems add extra headers for the same purpose - so they can easily track down spam reports and notify the correct people to stop it, or terminate their accounts.

This is something that is controlled by your hosting provider, so it's not something you can turn off.  If you don't want such headers inserted in your emails, you will have to move somewhere that doesn't do that, or setup your own mail server and send the mail directly through your own mail server.